# Controller Index Tolist Search Name by userID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _context.TBL_UserFunctionScope
                 .Select(p => new FunctionScopeViewModel() 
                  {
                    FunctionScopeID = p.FunctionScopeID,
                    ParentScopeName = _context.TBL_UserFunctionScope.Find(p.ParentScopeID).Name,
                    NameFunctionScope = p.Name,
                    NameFunction = p.TBL_UserFunction.Name
                  }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

I have a modelView with 4 attributes, and I want to show the info of `ParentScopeName` by the IDon on the ASP.NET MVC index page.

But I get an error on the line

```
ParentScopeName = _context.TBL_UserFunctionScope.Find(p.ParentScopeID).Name
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? Remember: we **cannot** see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind .... you need to **SHOW US** what the error is and what it says!

Comment: sorry... cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery

Comment: What are you trying to return? What is the relationship between `TBL_UserFunctionScope` and `ParentScope`? I'd guess you just need to use the navigation properties to the `ParentScope` name rather than trying to select a single row using another call to the context e.g. `ParentScopeName = p.ParentScopeID.Name`